# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.DynamicFileFilterWithCardinalityCheck has interface

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

While launching the spark-shell with iceberg dependencies, we got the following error:

```bash
spark-shell \
    --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark3-runtime:0.13.0 \
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.local=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.local.type=hadoop \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse=$PWD/warehouse
```

```sql
scala> spark.sql("CREATE TABLE local.db.table (id bigint, data string) USING iceberg")

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.DynamicFileFilterWithCardinalityCheck has interface org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.BinaryNode as super class
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
  at org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions.$anonfun$apply$8(IcebergSparkSessionExtensions.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.$anonfun$buildOptimizerRules$1(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:201)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.buildOptimizerRules(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.customOperatorOptimizationRules(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:259)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anon$2.extendedOperatorOptimizationRules(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.Optimizer.defaultBatches(Optimizer.scala:130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkOptimizer.defaultBatches(SparkOptimizer.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.Optimizer.batches(Optimizer.scala:383)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:200)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:179)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:197)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:197)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertOptimized(QueryExecution.scala:149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:167)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCteMap(QueryExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:260)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainString(QueryExecution.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:98)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:111)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:219)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:96)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:613)
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the spark version, we need to provide the latest runtime version. For example, in **Spark 3.2** we need to provide the **iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12** version.

1. **Spark 3.0**: iceberg-spark3-runtime:0.13.0
2. **Spark 3.1**: iceberg-spark-runtime-3.1_2.12
3. **Spark 3.2**: iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12

Comment: ` <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
  <artifactId> iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0</version> ` i just provide a depedency info in POM format for maven projects.